# Why does "cat config" in Terminal show different configurations between a repo created in a browser versus one created with the command line?

Tags: git, github, terminal

When I create the repository *test-repo* at GitHub using a browser and then clone that repository to my machine, I see this data with I enter `cat config` in Terminal:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/samuraijane/test-repo.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

But when I create the repository at GitHub using the command line

```
curl -u 'samuraijane' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d  "{\"name\":\"test-repo\"}"
git remote add origin https://github.com/samuraijane/test-repo.git
```

I see this data when I enter `cat config` in Terminal:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    ignorecase = true
    precomposeunicode = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/samuraijane/eric-test.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Why is `[branch master]` and its corresponding data missing when I create a repository using the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you used the browser to create the repository on GitHub, you also used the browser to create a commit within the repository.  That commit went on, and therefore created, the `master` branch.  When you cloned the repository, you got "their" (your) `master` branch as remote-tracking branch `origin/master` and `git clone` was then able to create-via-checkout a local branch `master` with `origin/master` as its upstream.

When you used `curl` to create the repository on GitHub, you did not create a commit within the repository.  The repository was therefore on an *unborn* `master` branch (the name `master` stored only in the `HEAD` reference, not as an actual branch).  When you cloned the repository, there were no branches, so you got no remote-tracking branches and `git clone` was unable to check out a local `master`.  So you have no branches in the clone, and `master` (which does not exist) cannot track remote-tracking branch `origin/master` (which also does not exist).

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed answer. I am not familiar with the term "unborn" as it relates to a master branch. Could you provide a link or other resource so that I could study this further? I've been reading https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2 but am only through chapter 2. Maybe it has this information in later chapters but if you can point me to something that explains this even more, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It's just a term Git uses for this state, where `HEAD` points to a branch even though that branch does not yet exist.  The state itself exists because `HEAD` always records the current branch and hence the current commit, but in a new repository (or when creating an orphan branch with `git checkout --orphan`) the branch does not / cannot point to any actual commit.  See the top 10 or so hits from a google search for git+unborn+branch: https://www.google.com/#q=git+unborn+branch